# Understanding awk ' NR%2 ... `

Tags: awk, scripting

Hi I am using 'Bash command line and shell scripts pocket primer' to study bash and I don't understand one chapter of awk, in which they illustrate printing even lines.

command:

```
awk ' NR%2 { printf "%s", $0; print "" }' < data
```

content of **data** text file:

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

output:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
```

My question is why does it print odd lines instead of even?

I did run NR%2==1 and NR%2==0 and it gives me odd / even output as predicted.
What am I missing?

Comment: *"When an expression is used in a Boolean context, if it has a numeric value, a value of zero is treated as false and any other value is treated as true."* - see for example [The Single UNIX ® Specification, Version 2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html#tag_000_000_108_002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NR` is the *one-based* record (line) number. `NR % 2` divides it by two and returns the remainder, so odd numbers give 1, even numbers give 0. In awk, non-zero numbers are truthy, and so the first, third etc. lines get printed.

This would be different if `NR` counted from zero.

Answer (score 1):

Because 1 counts as "true" and 0 counts as "false."  So when `NR % 2` is non-zero, the line is printed, hence you get the odd lines as output.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably knee-deep in text that tells you that in a shell script 0 means success and 1 failure. That is absolutely true. However, **awk is not shell**, awk is a completely separate tool that can be called from shell scripts, and awk doesn't test exit statuses, it tests boolean conditions where non-zero means true and 0 means false, just like in C and many other Algol-based languages.

Consider what that means to this shell script:

```
$ foo=0; if [ $foo ]; then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi
success
```

or the equivalent:

```
$ foo=0; if test $foo; then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi
success
```

vs this awk script:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ foo=0; if ( foo ) print "true"; else print "false" }'
false
```

Both scripts are testing for `0` but in shell that is an exit status that means success while in awk it's a condition that means false - 2 very different things.

In shell it's the **result** of `[ $foo ]` (or `test $foo`), i.e. executing the `[` shorthand for `test` on the exit status contained in `foo`, that is then evaluated by `if` as a condition and found to be true. You could implement the same thing in awk by writing:

```
awk '
    function test(exit_status) { return (exit_status==0 ? 1 : 0) }
    BEGIN{ foo=0; if ( test(foo) ) print "true"; else print "false" }
'
true
```

You said `I did run NR%2==1 and NR%2==0 and it gives me odd / even output as predicted.` - right, because in awk `1` (or any other non-zero value) is `true` in a conditional context and so the current line is printed while `0` is false and so the current line is not printed.

Comment: The exit code of a shell command is something entirely different than the numeric value of an expression. As in C, an arithmetic result of 0 means false, but the exit code might be success. Try `a=$(( 0 )); echo $a $?` and `a=$(( 1 )); echo $a $?`

Comment: That has nothing to do with anything I said in my answer.